# Mock scala objects method call in java class

Tags: java, scala, junit

I have a java code where I am calling a scala object's method (of a dependent library). For writing unit test I want to mock the scala object's method invocation

Operations.scala

```
object Operations {

     def load(spark: SparkSession, path: String): Dataset[Row] = {

     }
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public void callMethod() {
         Dataset<Row>  df = Operations.load(sparkSession, path);
    }
}
```

I want to write a Unit test for callMethod() and hence mock the Operations.load scala call. I did not find a way to do it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to change the signature of your `callMethod` method, one possible solution is to use interfaces and dependency injection.

Create an interface which gives you a `Dataset[Row]`:

```scala
trait ObtainDataSet {
  def obtain: DataSet[Row]
}
```

And then have your `callMethod` have a parameter that takes that interface:

```java
public void callMethod(ObtainDataSet obtainDataSet) {
  Dataset<Row>  df = obtainDataSet.obtain;
}
```

Then on production code you inject the real implementation using the `Operations.load` method:

```scala
class ObtainDataSetImpl(spark: SparkSession, path: String) extends ObtainDataSet {
  override def obtain: Dataset[Row] = Operations.load(sparkSession, path)
}
```

But you can easily swap that production implementation for something ad-hoc on the tests. You don't even need to use mocking frameworks:

```scala
class MyMock extends ObtainDataSet {
  override def obtain: DataSet[Row] = ??? // something useful for tests.
}
```

But if you want, [ScalaMock](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/testing_with_mock_objects) is normally used

Answer (score 0):

Here is how this is usually done ... I'll write it in scala, because java syntax is soooo much more verbose (and frankly, I don't remember it very well), but it is the same idea.

```
   trait Operations { 
       def load(s: SparkSession, path: String): DataSet[Row]
   }
   object Operations extends Operations {
       def load(s: SparkSession, path: String) = ??? // implementation here
   }

   class Main(operations: Operations = Operations) {
       callMethod(): Unit = {
         val df = operations.load(sparkSession, path);
         ...
         // do stuff 
      }
   }
```

and then in test, you write (this is with `Mockito`/`scalatest` but, again, same idea with whatever library you use for testing):

```
    val ops = mock[Operations]
    when(ops.load(any, any)).thenReturn(whatever)
    new Main(ops).callMethod(mock[SparkSession], "/foo/bar")
```

This approach is called "dependency injection": Your `Main` class has a "dependency" on `Operations`, that is now "injected" at run time rather than than being hardcoded as in your snippet. This allows you to use different dependency instances for production (actual `Operations` object) and test (the mock) runs.

Also, this is a separate topic, but I thought it is still worth mentioning: `Unit` (`void`) return type for the method you are testing doesn't seem like the best idea, and will likely cause you more problems testing it down the road (how do you make sure the method actually produced whatever side effects you are expecting from it?).

It would be better to make this method return the actual result, and have the caller take care of the side effects. Then you could easily test that it produces the result you expect:

```
   new Main(ops).callMethod(mock[SparkSession], "/foo/bar") shouldBe "ExpectedFooResult"
```